How can I Modify the labels in Salesforce Scheduler screenflow components
I am customizing the Screen Flows provided by Salesforce and need to modify some labels in the existing Salesforce components, but I can seem to find the options.
for example, in the "Select Service Resource and Appointment Time" component, I would like to the text "Who do you want to meet?" and "Select Service Appointment Time" to something else. Please see the screenshot below. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!


You can't. It's a delivered component with no inputs for overriding the labels you mentioned it uses. Your best bet is to put in a Case to let them know this gap (and they might just point you to create an Idea, but Case is worth it to get it on their radar).

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000QemVIUAZ/option-to-modify-labels-in-standard-components-in-salesforce-scheduler , an idea is created
